# Forest: four edges to one edge path

Tags: trees, forest

How to make four edges to one edge path?

[image]

I have made ​​it up here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[line width=1.5pt,\forestoption{edge}]
      (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-16pt) -|   
      (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=12pt,
  draw,
  fill=white,
  align=center,edge={->,thick},
  drop shadow
} 
[Menentukan Tujuan Penilaian
  [Memperhatikan Standar Kompetensinya
    [Menentukan KD-nya (KD1 + KD2 + KD3 dll)
      [Tes
      [Menentukan Materi Penting/\\Pendukung KD: UKRK
      [Tepat diujikan secara tertulis/lisan?
      [Tepat
      [Bentuk Objektif\\ (pg{,} isian{,} dll)]
      [Bentuk\\ Uraian]
      ]
      [Tidak Tepat
      [Tes Perbuatan
      [{\textbullet} kinerja (performance)\\
        {\textbullet} penugasan (project)\\
        {\textbullet} hasil karya (product)\\
        {\textbullet} dll]
      ]]]]]
      [NonTes
        [{\textbullet} Pengamatan/Observasi (Sikap{,} Portofolio{,} \emph{Life Skills})\\{\textbullet} Tes sikap\\{\textbullet} dll]
]]]]
;
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Draw the node as the child of any one of its parents and add the arrows from the other 3 parents after finishing the tree (but before closing the `forest` environment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this idea, maybe it could be useful.

Add the *"conclusion"* like a new node (i named it `(end)`, this allows center it regarding to the tree), name each leaf `(branch ..)` and after join with edges.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[line width=1.5pt,\forestoption{edge}]
      (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-16pt) -|   
      (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=12pt,
  draw,
  fill=white,
  align=center,edge={->,thick},
  drop shadow
} 
[Menentukan Tujuan Penilaian
  [Memperhatikan Standar Kompetensinya
    [Menentukan KD-nya (KD1 + KD2 + KD3 dll)
      [Tes
      [Menentukan Materi Penting/\\Pendukung KD: UKRK
      [Tepat diujikan secara tertulis/lisan?
      [Tepat
      [Bentuk Objektif\\ (pg{,} isian{,} dll),name=branch 1]
      [Bentuk\\ Uraian,name=branch 2]
      ]
      [Tidak Tepat
      [Tes Perbuatan
      [{\textbullet} kinerja (performance)\\
        {\textbullet} penugasan (project)\\
        {\textbullet} hasil karya (product)\\
        {\textbullet} dll,name=branch 3]
      ]]]]]
      [NonTes
        [{\textbullet} Pengamatan/Observasi (Sikap{,} Portofolio{,} \emph{Life Skills})\\{\textbullet} Tes sikap\\{\textbullet} dll,name=branch 4]
]]]]
\path  let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
([yshift=-5mm]current bounding box.south) node
[ minimum width=\n1, % Width of node equals to width of previous tree
  anchor=north,
  draw,
  fill=white,
  align=center,
  drop shadow] (end)
{Ikuti Kaidah Penulisan Soal Dan Sunsunla Pedoman Penskorannya};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4} {\draw[->,thick](branch \i)--(branch \i|-end.north);}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: (+1) This does a nicer job of placement than my answer! (Though I don't understand *what* it does exactly....)

Comment: @cfr What I do is to measure (width) of the @kalakay's tree and save in the `\n1` register (using the `let` operation), then to create a new node with this measurement as *minimum width* (inconvenient because i must pass all options, unless i create a new style). I put this new node centered fixing it in `([yshift=-5mm]current bounding box.south)`, then i reference it (which you also did, with `parent`) and i draw the arrows.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is the `let` operation I need to look at (and maybe `current bounding box` but that seems relatively self-explanatory).

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[line width=1.5pt,\forestoption{edge}]
      (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-16pt) -|
      (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=12pt,
  draw,
  fill=white,
  align=center,edge={->,thick},
  drop shadow
}
[Menentukan Tujuan Penilaian
  [Memperhatikan Standar Kompetensinya
    [Menentukan KD-nya (KD1 + KD2 + KD3 dll)
      [Tes
      [Menentukan Materi Penting/\\Pendukung KD: UKRK
      [Tepat diujikan secara tertulis/lisan?
      [Tepat
      [Bentuk Objektif\\ (pg{,} isian{,} dll), name=parent1]
      [Bentuk\\ Uraian, name=parent2]
      ]
      [Tidak Tepat
      [Tes Perbuatan
      [{{\textbullet} kinerja (performance)\\
        {\textbullet} penugasan (project)\\
        {\textbullet} hasil karya (product)\\
        {\textbullet} dll}, parent anchor=south, l sep+=5pt, child anchor=north
          [Text of final node here which is supposed to be long and so take up a large amount of horizontal space., name=final child]
      ]
      ]]]]]
      [NonTes
        [{\textbullet} Pengamatan/Observasi (Sikap{,} Portofolio{,} \emph{Life Skills})\\{\textbullet} Tes sikap\\{\textbullet} dll, name=parent4]
]]]]
;
  \draw [->, thick] (parent1.south) -- (final child.north -| parent1.south);
  \draw [->, thick] (parent2.south) -- (final child.north -| parent2.south);
  \draw [->, thick] (parent4.south) -- (final child.north -| parent4.south);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: many parents, one child]